# SugarCRM7.9 - instaling composer packages via module manifest?

Tags: php, composer-php, manifest, sugarcrm, guzzle

I've built custom module for SugarCRM7, but I need to use custom libs (guzzlehttp and psr/http-message) which are not present in SugarCRM. Is there any way to add my own composer.json to installable package so the composer file would be executed after module install or maybe should I do it using manifest somehow?

I've tried to simply copy vendor files using copy in manifest.php but it doesn't seem to work and I need to execute it without comand line access.

I didn't find any word about composer in Sugar dev docs, so I'm asking here. Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to go is packaging all files in the installable package. But there is a problem with too many files due to the http post size. So if some of your files are missing try zipping the lib and unzip via a post_install script.

Comment: I just wasn't sure about putting libs into the installable package, but it seems to be the only way, thanks for the hint about zipping the libs!